# Highlight gaps on joined surfaces - CATIA V5 (GSD)

Tags: cad, surface-modelling, catia

Is there a possibility to highlight the gaps that occur when surfaces are joined?

The gaps are displayed within the command. But after the surfaces are joined, the gap is no longer visible, but it does exist.

In the first picture, the gap is highlighted in green, as I am within the command.

But in the second picture the surfaces are joined, but the gap is not visible.

Please help.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the boundary command on the joined surface, it creates a boundary on the edge of the entire surface and also highlights the gaps!